# Android AssetManager.list() Incredibly Slow

Tags: android, performance, ddms

I'm attempting to use the functionality of AssetManager.list() for a game, but a single call takes an incredible amount of time (~0.5-1.0 seconds).  To make matters worse, the only source I can find for AssetManager lists the following definition, without any clear subclasses:

```
public native final String[] list(String path)
    throws IOException;
```

[image]

While this should be a slow method, times of up to a second are ridiculous (this is testing on a variety of Nexus 7's and 10's).  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an index-file that is generated by an automatic Eclipe-Builder.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639530/342947

Comment: Ah!  You are a saint!  My plan was basically to write something like this over the night, but this will be much easier.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was just verifying to make sure everything was created properly. :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Disclaimer: Self promotion. I created a gradle plugin specifically for adding compile time safety, which has the added benefit of automatically generating a list for each folder. Check it out at https://github.com/oriley-me/crate