# Gradle+Java+Android+AIDE making a recursive list from assets directory....

Tags: android, gradle

i would have loved to put this as a comment to the original question, but i have not enough access rights to make comments....
i tried to use the answer of [Android+Gradle: list directories into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569983/androidgradle-list-directories-into-a-file) for an android java project developed with AIDE....
as far as i understand all this gradle/maven stuff AIDE still uses gradle v 1.

estracted from the general build.gradle file:
    dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'}

so i added the whole new assets reading task to the app build.gradle (in the app director) that now looks this way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nohkumado.quelkar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }   

//try to compile a asset directory listing....
    task indexAssets 
    {
       description 'Index Build Variant assets for faster lookup by AssetManager later'
       ext.assetsSrcDir = file( "${projectDir}/src/main/assets" )        
       ext.assetsBuildDir = file( "${buildDir}/assets" )
       inputs.dir assetsSrcDir
       //outputs.dir assetsBuildDir
       doLast 
   {
           android.applicationVariants.each 
    { 
                   target ->
           ext.variantPath = "${buildDir.name}/assets/${target.dirName}"
           println "copyAssetRec:${target.dirName} -> ${ext.variantPath}"

           def relativeVariantAssetPath = projectDir.name.toString() + "/" + ext.variantPath.toString()
           def assetIndexFile = new File(relativeVariantAssetPath +"/assets.index")
           def contents = ""

           def tree = fileTree(dir: "${ext.variantPath}", exclude: ['**/.svn/**', '*.index'])

           tree.visit 
                         { 
                           fileDetails ->
               contents += "${fileDetails.relativePath}" + "\n"
           }
           assetIndexFile.write contents
           }
       }
    }
    indexAssets.dependsOn 
    {
      tasks.matching { task -> task.name.startsWith( 'merge' ) && task.name.endsWith( 'Assets' ) }
    }
    tasks.withType( Compile ) 
    {
       compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn indexAssets
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project('::../UtilsApp:nohutils')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

so i thought i did it right..... but seems not, adding that task to the gradle file, break the dependcies directive meaning that suddenly all my imports from the external library nohutils don't work anymore.....

and in fact, it happens as soon as i declare, even an empty "task indexAssets".....
unfortunately, each time i try to apply what i read in the gradle manual, fails in AIDE and since AIDE has no manual whatsoever, its just dabbling in the dark....

so if anyone has a possible explanation/solution i will gladly take it....

Comment: AIDE does not have support for quite a lot of things, and this could well be one of them, unfortunately.